# based on count pull images from an another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

i have two tables :

**ist table for the images of badges :**

[image: ii]

**again there is one more table which contains the count for the badges won by a particular employee :**
[image: enter imagerr description here]

**for a particular employee , (using the EmployeeID) I want to display the images of all the badges which have a count greater than 0.**

For instance, for phil in the above table, all the badges except slacker has a count greater than 0.So the images of all these badges with count 1 will be displayed.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Yo'd better redesign the second table as (EmpId,BageId,count) and simply use JOIN.

Comment: @Serg I understand I can use inner join here.Now the point is how do I add badgeId in the second table.Based on that entity I can join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t1.badgeImage
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on (t2.intoTheGame > 0 and t1.BadgeName = 'intoTheGame') or
        (t2.getALife > 0 and t1.BadgeName = 'getALife') or
        . . .
where t2.employeeid = ?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,This Query works fine as your expected result.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID,EMPLOYEENAME,A.BADGENAME,BADGEID,BADGEIMAGE,COUNTS FROM (
SELECT EMPLOYEEID,EMPLOYEENAME,BADGENAME,COUNTS FROM EMPLOYEE--SECONDTABLE
UNPIVOT(
COUNTS FOR BADGENAME IN (INTOTHEGAME,GETALIFE,SLOGGER,SLACKER,BEYONDCALLOFDUTY)
)PVT
)A INNER JOIN BADGES B ON A.BADGENAME=B.BADGENAME----FIRST TABLE
WHERE COUNTS >0
```

Comment: this is not going to take me anywhere.ther is no count attribute here. Anyways upvote coz u tried.

Comment: @jane, I've added a counts column in the select list. Let's check one more.

Comment: ther is no attribute by the name of "BadgeName" in second tABLE

Comment: You'd better post the expected Result @Jane.